# extract data from several images to different shapefile columns using GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis

I am now working in grass and I want to extract raster values from several images to a shapefile. I have already created the columns in the .shp where the raster values will be stored but I am facing difficulties on how will I make the loop...

What I want is to extract the values of image_1 to column_a, values of image_2 to column_b etc etc... The problem that I have is that I can't make the loop for two variables (raster image and shapefile column) together... It must be easy but I am new in grass and bash in general as you must have already understood.

The command that I used is "v.what.rast"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a loop to iterate through your data using `v.what.rast`. If you update
your field names with an integer (e.g. column_1, column_2 ..), the
following loop should work.

```
    i=0
    for image in `g.mlist type=rast patt=*image_regexp*`
    do
      v.what.rast vector=target_vector raster=$image column=column_$1
      $((i++))
   done
```

I'm almost certain that you'll need to import your Shp file into the GRASS
native vector format using `v.in.ogr`, because as far a I know, `v.external` creates a read-only link to the dataset.